# Optional Spring bean references

Tags: java, spring

In my application I am using ContextLoaderListener to load context files from many jars using:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:META-INF/contextBeans.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

This means I can reference beans from other jars without doing import.

In the application there are multiple deployment options and in some deployments jars can be excluded. To support that I would like some bean references to be optional. For example:

```
<bean id="mainAppBean" class="com.someapp.MyApplication">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="localBean"/>
     <constructor-arg index="1" ref="optionalBeanReference1"/>
    <constructor-arg index="2" ref="optionalBeanReference2"/>
 </bean>
```

In the example above I would like to have optionalBeanReference1 equal null if the reference was not found (mark it optional in some way)

Can this be done in Spring? or what method do you recommend for handling dynamic references?

Comment: Future readers.  You may want to explore the "Java Config" way.  Which is not "spring-xml" and it is not "@Annotation/@Autowire/@Inject". but rather.. you have a class (sometimes called composition root) where you "code up the beans" in (usually/preferred) a SINGLE place.  And then you can look into this:  https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ObjectProvider.html#getIfAvailable--

Comment: Here is an example . find the "getIfAvailable() example" in this URL : https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-core/object-provider.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> what method do you recommend for handling dynamic references?

I think @cristian's @Autowired answer is a good one.  That will call the setter methods if the beans of that type are available.  However, if you have multiple beans of the same type, I believe Spring throws an exception.  If you cannot use @Autowired for this or some other reason, I see a couple of solutions:

1. You could make your class `ApplicationContextAware` and lookup the beans in the context yourself:

   ```
   public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
       if (applicationContext.containsBean("optionalBeanReference1")) {
           setOptionalBeanReference1(
               (OptionalBeanReference1)applicationContext.bean(
                   "optionalBeanReference1");
       }
       ...
   }
   ```
2. You could invert the dependency.  Each of the optional classes could set *themselves* on the mainAppBean.  I use this in certain situations when a direct dependency would cause loops or other problems.

   ```
   <bean id="optionalBeanReference1" class="com.someapp.SomeClass">
       <constructor-arg index="0" ref="mainAppBean"/>
   </bean>
   ```

   Then in the SomeClass:

   ```
   public SomeClass(com.someapp.MyApplication mainAppBean) {
       mainAppBean.setOptionalBeanReference1(this);
   }
   ```
3. You could stay with your direct dependency and then either import a file with the beans defined or import another file where you define the beans as having null values by using a factory bean.  See this [factory code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163182/intentionally-setting-a-spring-bean-to-null).

Good luck.

Comment: I used something similar to the first option, where after the bean is loaded I check if other beans exist as well. This seems like the best way without annotations

Comment: The 1 seems to be an anti-pattern of IoC. You're using spring like a service provider. personnaly, I'm not fond of IoC (there are good sides, but they don't require the lost of control), but either you use it or you don't. Messing around is probably the most dangerous.

Answer (score 26):

My best guess is to use [autowire](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation)-ing with required false. Don't know how you can express this in XML but using annotation configuration this would look like:

```
@Autowired(required=false)
```

Comment: Oh, yea, and setter injection is probably better for this type of situations.

Comment: This sounds good however I am unable to use Spring annotations in the project for now.

Answer (score 21):

With recent versions of Spring (tested with spring 4.1) and Java Configuration and Java 8, you can use Optional in parameters, and are only autowired if available.

```
@Autowired
public MyApplication(Optional<YourOptionalObject> maybeObject) {
    // do something with the optional autowired
}
```

Comment: See the Spring improvement ticket here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11833 and an actual example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485878/can-inject-be-made-optional-in-jsr-330-like-autowirerequired-false

Answer (score 6):

There's no built-in mechanism for this. However, you could write a pretty trivial `FactoryBean` implementation to do this for you, something like this:

```
public class OptionalFactoryBean extends AbstractFactoryBean<Object> implements BeanNameAware {

    private String beanName;

    @Override
    public void setBeanName(String beanName) {
        this.beanName = BeanFactoryUtils.originalBeanName(beanName);

    }

    @Override
    protected Object createInstance() throws Exception {
        if (getBeanFactory().containsBean(beanName)) {
            return getBeanFactory().getBean(beanName);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
<bean id="mainAppBean" class="com.someapp.MyApplication">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="localBean"/>    
    <constructor-arg index="1">
       <bean name="optionalBeanReference1" class="com.someapp.OptionalBeanFactory"/>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="2">
       <bean name="optionalBeanReference2" class="com.someapp.OptionalBeanFactory"/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 5):

Given that the bean references in your XML config are defined via *expression language* (EL) you can do the following:

```
<property name="cache" value="#{getObject('optionalCache')}" />
```

which makes use of the `BeanExpressionContext.getObject()` method. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13091720/12960) for more details.