# How to inject a bean only when it exists

Tags: java, spring, option-type, spring-el

I have the following structure of spring context files ( `->` stands for 'includes') :

```
A1.xml -> B.xml & C.xml
A2.xml -> B.xml
```

`C.xml` defines a bean `c`

`B.xml` defines a bean `b` with a dependency on `c`

Obviously this fails for A2, because there is no `c` defined in the context `A2`.

**How can I specify something like: if you have `c` in the context inject it in `b` otherwise just inject `null`?**

I looked into Spring EL but

```
<property name="b" ref="#{ @c?:null}" />
```

Just gave me a `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` for a name which seemed to be the value of `b.toString()` !?

Btw: I already know that this thing is messy as hell and should be cleaned up as fast as possible.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The #root object of the SpEL Expression is a BeanExpressionContext, you can invoke the `getObject()` method on that context; it returns null if the bean is not declared...

```
<property name="bar" value="#{getObject('bar')}" />
```

Note: you use `value` not `ref` because it returns the bean, not the bean definition.

Here's the code from `getObject()`

```
public Object getObject(String key) {
    if (this.beanFactory.containsBean(key)) {
        return this.beanFactory.getBean(key);
    }
    else if (this.scope != null){
        return this.scope.resolveContextualObject(key);
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I quite agree with cleaning up your XML :-)

If you're using annotation based injection, you might try [this trick](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html)

```
@Autowired( required=false )
```

I'm unsure whether this will work in your situation, but it's worth a try.