# How do you make @Resource optional?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

Is there some way to make @Resource optional? This means if I don't have a bean of type requested by @Resource, I won't get Exception, but it would be just set to null.

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957430/optional-spring-bean-references.It might helpful to you

Comment: ok looks like it isn't possible. Had to use @Autowired(required = false). Not what I exactly wanted, but it will do

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ok looks like it isn't possible. Had to use @Autowired(required = false). Not what I exactly wanted, but it will do.

Comment: It makes the resource optional, so it is what you want to do, even if you don't know this :)

Comment: Autowired and Resource are two different things, try to inject <util:map id="myMap"> with Autowired - it will work only for beans but not for resources

Comment: @DanubianSailor — `@Autowired` is a Spring annotation, whereas `@Resource` is a common Java annotation.  If you're not using Spring, then `@Autowired` wouldn't even be an option.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `@Value` and default value (`#{null}`) on Resource type.

```
@Value("some-data.txt:#{null}") Resource resource
```

If file some-data.txt does not exist property isn't set as `null` but a resource with a non-existing file. You can call `resource.exists()` instead of `resource != null`.

```
public ResourceExample(@Value("some-data.txt:#{null}") Resource resource) {
    if (resource.exists()) {
        something(resource.getFile());
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked for me without `#{null}`. The `.exists()` does the job.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a custom factory bean to achieve this:

```
public class OptionalFactoryBean<T> implements BeanFactoryAware, FactoryBean<T> {

    private String beanName;

    public void setBeanName(String beanName) {
         this.beanName = beanName;
    }

    @Override
    public T getObject() throws Exception {
        T result;
        try {
            result = beanFactory.getBean(beanName);
        } catch (NoSuchBeanDefinitionException ex) {
            result = null;
        }
        return result;
    }

    private BeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Override
    public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) {
        this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
    }

    private Class<?> objectType = Object.class;

    public void setObjectType(Class<?> objectType) {
        this.objectType = objectType != null? objectType : Object.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return objectType;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSingleton() {
         return true;
    }    
}
```

Spring configuration for your optional bean would be:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="mypackage.OptionalFactoryBean" scope="singleton">
    <property name="beanName" value="myRealBean"/>
    <property name="objectType" value="mypackage.MyRealBean"/>
</bean>
```

And you would get `null` injected. Then you could define:

```
<bean id="myRealBean" class="mypackage.MyRealBean" ...>
    <!-- .... -->
</bean>
```

if you wanted to inject some particular bean.