# Can @Inject be made optional in JSR 330 (like @Autowire(required=false)?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, cdi

Spring's `@Autowire` can be configured such that Spring will not throw an error if no matching autowire candidates are found: `@Autowire(required=false)`

Is there an equivalent JSR-330 annotation?  `@Inject` always fails if there is no matching candidate.  Is there any way I can use `@Inject` but not have the framework fail if no matching types are found?  I haven't been able to find any documentation to that extent.

Comment: Really not a good idea: they choose to *not* do it in CDI in order to make sure that all dependencies are there. Should you really have a null check on a dependency? Seems like an architecture problem, and some solution could be to inject an interface, which could have a no-op implementation. Null if not found is really bad design: is it not found on purpose, or because of a programming mistake?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No... there is no equivalent for optional in JSR 330... if you want to use optional injection then you will have to stick with the framework specific `@Autowired` annotation

Comment: [I can't seem to find the spec document for the JSR330, if there is one.](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=330) Do you know the reasoning behind the decision not to include a kind of `@Optional` feature?

Comment: >>Do you know the reasoning behind the decision not to include a kind of @Optional feature?<< I believe the reason is existance of Provider's. javax.inject.Provider.get() MAY return null, so if one injects Provider, one can achieve the same result as with optional injection

Answer (score 38):

You can use `java.util.Optional`.
If you are using **Java 8** and your **Spring** version is `4.1` or above (see [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11833)), instead of

```
@Autowired(required = false)
private SomeBean someBean;
```

You can just use `java.util.Optional` class that came with **Java 8**. Use it like:

```
@Inject
private Optional<SomeBean> someBean;
```

This instance will never be `null`, and you can use it like:

```
if (someBean.isPresent()) {
   // do your thing
}
```

This way you can also do constructor injection, with some beans required and some beans optional, gives great flexibility.

Note: Unfortunately Spring does not support **Guava**'s `com.google.common.base.Optional` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20241080/1005102)), so this method will work only if you are using Java 8 (or above).

Comment: Interesting option.  I wasn't on Java8 when I originally posted the question but I like the principle.  Thanks for pointing it out.  I guess technically, there is still no real option using JSR330, but this is a good use of the J8 advantages to get around it.

Comment: I am using Java 8 and Spring 4.2.7, and it works like a charm. But is the spec say how to manage "Optional" type? By the way, it is a very reasonable implementation. I like.

Comment: Of course, brilliant. Just what I needed and much cleaner than an optionally null bean.

Comment: Great answer! Isn't the annotation parameter called `required` though?

Comment: @UtkuÖzdemir: That was incredibly quick for a 1.5 year old answer! Cheers! :)

Comment: But you should be aware that using the `java.util.Optional` as a field is discouraged in general. It does not even implement the `Serializable` interface.

Comment: @SergeyPetunin yes, true, I used it for the sake of example. Better to use constructor injection and a nullable field. By the way, you should be aware that using Java Serialization is discouraged in general.

Comment: Sure, you probably wouldn't want to serialize the bean yourself, but the framework could do this at some point in time, for example, if it is a session-scoped bean.

Answer (score 13):

Instance injection is often overlooked. It adds great flexibility. Check the availability of the dependency prior to getting it. An unsatisfied get will throw  an exception which is expensive. Use:

```
@Inject
Instance<SomeType> instance;
SomeType instantiation;

if (!instance.isUnsatisfied()) {
    instantiation = instance.get();
}
```

You can restrict the injection candidates as normal:

```
@Inject
@SomeAnnotation
Instance<SomeType> instance;
```

Comment: See this answer by Giovanni Silva

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't know about the `javax.enterprise.inject.Instance` class.  But what JSR/pkg is it part of?  It doesn't seem to be part of JSR-330.  Is this a JEE6 specific thing?

Comment: java.enterprise.inject.Instance is specified in JSR 299: Contexts and Dependency Injection for the JavaTM EE platform. As the title states, it is only applicable to the JEE platform. JSR 330: Dependency Injection for Java is a much lighter specification with no reliance on the JEE platform. It is a shame that JSR 330 did not incorporate all of the non JEE specific features of JSR 299, such as java.enterprise.inject.Instance. Why this did not happen I’ll leave to others to conjecture.

Answer (score 7):

It's is possible to create a optional injection point!

You need to use injection lookup as documented in http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/injection.html#lookup

```
@Inject
Instance<Type> instance;

// In the code
try {
   instance.get();
}catch (Exception e){

}
```

Or even all instances of a type

```
@Inject
Instance<List<Type>> instances
```

Also the get() method is lazy evaluated if you need. The default Injection evaluates at Startup time and throw an exception if no beans are found that could be injected, the bean will be injected at runtime of course, but the application will not start if this is impossible.
In the documentation you will find more examples, including how to filter the instances injected and much, much more.

Comment: this is only true for Weld?

Comment: No this is true for any CDI implementation.

Comment: Ahh Ok I thought as we are talking about JSR-330 this would be a solution for JSR-330.

Comment: Context and Dependency Injection is not the same as JSR-330? I don't think so.

Comment: For a JSR-330 solution, one can use javax.inject.Provider to similar effect.

Comment: Is `javax.enterprise.inject.Instance` specific to JEE6?  I don't see it in the JSR-330 specs/pkg.

Answer (score 5):

The `AutowiredAnnotationBeanFactoryPostProcessor` (Spring 3.2) contains this method to determine if a supported 'Autowire' annotation is required or not:

```
    /**
     * Determine if the annotated field or method requires its dependency.
     * <p>A 'required' dependency means that autowiring should fail when no beans
     * are found. Otherwise, the autowiring process will simply bypass the field
     * or method when no beans are found.
     * @param annotation the Autowired annotation
     * @return whether the annotation indicates that a dependency is required
     */
    protected boolean determineRequiredStatus(Annotation annotation) {
        try {
            Method method = ReflectionUtils.findMethod(annotation.annotationType(), this.requiredParameterName);
            if (method == null) {
                // annotations like @Inject and @Value don't have a method (attribute) named "required"
                // -> default to required status
                return true;
            }
            return (this.requiredParameterValue == (Boolean) ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(method, annotation));
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            // an exception was thrown during reflective invocation of the required attribute
            // -> default to required status
            return true;
        }
    }
```

In short, no, not by default.

The method name that is being looked for by default is 'required', which is not a field on the `@Inject` annotation, thus, `method` will be `null` and `true` will be returned.

You may be able to change that by subclassing this `BeanPostProcessor` and overriding the `determineRequiredStatus(Annotation)` method to return true, or rather, something 'smarter'.

Comment: Or implement your own `@Optional` behavior.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I presume that implementing my own `@Optional` behaviour would include the suggestion here of creating my own BeanPostProccessor, but that seems like a lot of overkill.  I find it a shame that JSR330 didn't include the @Optional annotation.

Comment: @EricB. Yeah, that would be the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Spring supports `@Nullable` with `@Inject`:

```
@Inject
@Nullable
void setSomeBean(SomeBean someBean)
```