# How does @RequestParam in Spring handle Guava's Optional?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, guava, nullable, option-type

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/contact.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public final ModelAndView contact(
        @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) Optional<String> name) {
```

How does Spring's `@RequestMapping` handle an [`Optional`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Optional.html) from [Guava library](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) if the parameter value is not required and nothing is sent?

Will it be:

- Set to `null`
- Set to `Optional.absent()`

Can `Optional.fromNullable(T)` be used to accept the request?

Comment: I believe that it will be `null`, because Spring does not know anything of Guava, at least by default.

Comment: It may be possible to register a `PropertyEditor` to tell Spring how to convert the `name` request parameter to an `Optional`. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#beans-beans-conversion

Comment: There's no such thing as `Optional.of(null)~.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**EDIT (October 2015):** Spring 4 handles `java.util.Optional` (from Java 8) out of the box and *guarantees that `Optional` itself is not null*, but original question was about Guava's `com.google.common.base.Optional` which usage as `@RequestParam` is highly discouraged in this specific case (because it *can* be null).

**ORIGINAL ANSWER** (about Guava's `Optional`):

Don't do that, just use `String` and let Spring handle `null` in its way.

`Optional<T>` is supposed to be used as [*return value*](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained#whats-the-point) and rarely as a parameter. In this particular case Spring will map missing `"name"` parameter to `null`, so even if after implementing custom [property editor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#beans-beans-conversion-customeditor-registration) you'll finish with `null` check:

```
@RequestMapping("foo")
@ResponseBody
public String foo(@RequestParam(required = false) final Optional name) {
  return "name: " + (name == null ? "null" : name.get());
}
```

which is completely unnecessary (and missuses `Optional`), because it can be achieved with:

```
@RequestMapping("foo")
@ResponseBody
public String foo(@RequestParam(required = false) final String name) {
  return "name: " + (name == null ? "null" : name);
}
```

Comment: as far as I know latest version of Spring works good with jdk Optional type

Comment: @Yura Spring 4 handles [`java.util.Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) out of the box, but I'm quite sure that [`com.google.common.base.Optional`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html) (which OP uses) is not supported.

Comment: methodName(@RequestParam("appRefNo") String appRefNo, 
           @RequestParam(value="appStatus", required=false) String appStatus)

Answer (score 4):

I recommend to use the Java 8 version: `java.util.Optional`. Look at the Oracle documentation in http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html.
Also put a name to the variable, specially if your using Spring 3 or higher:.

```
import java.util.Optional;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class LoginController
{

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getLoginPage(@RequestParam(name = "error", required = false) Optional<String> errorMsg)
    {
        //error.ifPresent(LOGGER::debug); //Java 8 with Optional
        return new ModelAndView("login", "error", errorMsg);
    }

}
```

`java.util.Optional` is very useful for managing optional parametrers, like *errors* in Spring.

Comment: Isn't the parameter name specified with value instead of name?

Comment: As you may see here https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html, value is an alias of name

Comment: I am using like bellow 
search(@RequestParam("appRefNo") String appRefNo, @RequestParam(value="appStatus", required=false) String appStatus) { }

Comment: @Md.Kamruzzaman your approach is right, but i would rather not to deal with `null` parameters and using `Optional` the code is shorter and you can provide more features using high order functions.

Answer (score 0):

The answer on you question will be optional parameter first is setting to null.

In Spring HandlerMethodInvoker I found resolveRequestParam method

```
    Object paramValue = null;
    ...
    if (multipartRequest != null) {
    ...
    // Check if this is multipart request and set paramValue in this case.
    }
    // Otherwise
    if (paramValue == null) {
        String[] paramValues = webRequest.getParameterValues(paramName);
        if (paramValues != null) {
            paramValue = (paramValues.length == 1 ? paramValues[0] : paramValues);
        }
    }
    if (paramValue == null) {
       if (defaultValue != null) {
            paramValue = resolveDefaultValue(defaultValue);
        }
        else if (required) {
            raiseMissingParameterException(paramName, paramType);
        }
        ...
     }
     ...
```

So first we check if it is a multipart request. Otherwise we get parameters values by parameter name from servlet request. Finally if parameter value null we check if parameter is required. If required we throw exception, otherwise return null.