# Tag authentication-manager with optional provider bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, xsd-validation

I have two spring profiles that are independent from each other, like below:

```
<beans profile="prof1">
    <security:authentication-manager id="authenticationManager" erase-credentials="true">
        <security:authentication-provider ref="1" />
        <security:authentication-provider ref="2" />
        <security:authentication-provider ref="3" />
    </security:authentication-manager>
</beans>

<beans profile="prof2" >
    <security:authentication-manager id="authenticationManager" erase-credentials="true">
        <security:authentication-provider ref="0" />
        <security:authentication-provider ref="1" />
        <security:authentication-provider ref="2" />
        <security:authentication-provider ref="3" />
    </security:authentication-manager>
</beans>
```

For instance, I can enable profile in the following way:

```
|prof1|prof2|
|true |true |
|true |false|
|false|true |
|false|false|
```

When the last option is specified spring complain that **authentication-manager** is missed.

In order to fix this I looked for something like **"optional reference to spring bean"**.

Namely the idea was to extract manager from the profile like below:

```
 <security:authentication-manager id="authenticationManager" erase-credentials="true">
            <security:authentication-provider ref="0-optional-reference" />
            <security:authentication-provider ref="1" />
            <security:authentication-provider ref="2" />
            <security:authentication-provider ref="3" />
        </security:authentication-manager>
```

Then make bean with name "0" as optional bean. I've found the following post [Optional Spring bean references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957430/optional-spring-bean-references) but it looks like any options does not work for me because I cannot replace "ref" attribute with "value" because of spring xsd.

It would be good to know any options how can I specify optional bean for **authentication-provider** spring tag.

Answer (score 0):

Spring complains because when neither profiles are active, the beans definitions declared in the `prof1` and `prof2` `<beans>` blocks are not taken into account and therefore not loaded in the `BeanFactory`. 
So at runtime, Spring Security doesn't find any bean of type `AuthenticationManager` and complains.

What you could do is declare a "default" `AuthenticationManager` in a new `<beans>` block that would be active only if neither `prof1` nor `prof2` are active :

```
<beans profile="!prof1 !prof2">
    <security:authentication-manager id="authenticationManager">
    ...
    </security:authentication-manager>
</beans>
```

Comment: Thanks Olivier for prompt answer. I am just thinking about the case when both profiles are active. And which one will be considered valid. It looks like both declaration <beans profile="prof1">,<beans profile="prof2"> will be valid.

Comment: When both profiles are active, the 2 `AuthenticationManagers` become available for injection and have equal "weight", which can lead to Spring complaining that it found multiple implementations of a given bean type. To solve that problem, you can mark either one as "primary" : `<bean primary="true" .../>`, so that it takes precedence over during injection lookup.

Comment: I've tried this for beans tag, but it looks like it is not allowed by spring xsd to set such attribute. Will be it possible to specify any other attribute instead?

Comment: The "primary" attribute must be set on a `<bean>` tag, not `<beans>`. Now that you mention it, I'm not sure if the specialized `<security:authentication-manager>` tag can bear it directly (I cannot test that right now, sorry). If not, you will have to resort to declaring the authentication manager "by hand" using plain old bean declarations.

Comment: Yes, but I don't have bean, only the context that specified above. Namely authentication-manager inside of the beans.