# Skip optional bean reference property

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, design-patterns, javabeans

I have two beans for the same class:

```
<bean id="child1" class"abc.Parent"/>

<bean id="child2" class"abc.Parent">
    <property name"service" ref="fooService"/
</beans>
```

Class-

```
class Parent
{
    private FooService service;

    public void doStuff() {
        service.doFooStuff();
    }

    public FooService getService() {
        return service;
    }

    public void setService(FooService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }
}
```

I don't want to populate `service` for `child2`. Is there any design pattern of spring based check to ensure that nothing happens for `child2` apart from the good old *null check*?

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957430/optional-spring-bean-references) looks similar. I am wondering if an "optional" suggestion would be a good idea - feels clean and self explanatory to me but I have never use it myself.