# Spring XML Bean Configuration - Specify nullable constructor arguments

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, xml-configuration

I am trying to configure a nullable parameter for constructor based dependency injection. I am using XML Bean Configuration.

The question is - is there a way to achieve the same as `@Autowired(required = false)` or `@Nullable` from Spring XML Bean configuration?

I am aware that for annotation based config, we have the possibility to use something like:

```
public MyConfiguration(MyServiceA myServiceA, **@Autowired(required = false)** MyServiceB myServiceB){
  this.myServiceA = myServiceA;
  this.myServiceB = myServiceB;   
}
```

I would expect that exists something like:

```
<bean id="recreatePreviewService" class="com.celum.internal.web.preview.RecreatePreviewService">
    <constructor-arg index="0" **required="false"** ref="recreateTicketProcessor">
</bean>
```

Is that even possible? My Spring version is 5.3.29.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Optional Spring bean references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957430/optional-spring-bean-references)

Comment: Kind of. I was looking at the same question before posting this, and most of the answers include some additional magic or 'workarounds', not what I was hoping for. Anyway, thanks for checking out!