# How to set null to Integer in spring context

Tags: java, spring

this is small part of my context:

```
<property name="a" value="1"/> where a is Integer.
```

How I can set null to this value ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Intentionally setting a Spring bean to null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163182/intentionally-setting-a-spring-bean-to-null)

Comment: @JigarJoshi - That question is asking how to set a bean to null. This one is asking how to set a property to null.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the element `<null/>` to indicate a null value:

```
<property name="a" value="1"/><null/></property>
```

**Edit:** There is more information in the official spring 2.5 documentation here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-null-element

Comment: Add a [link](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-null-element) would be good.

Comment: +1 http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-null-element

Answer (score 2):

There is the way to set the null value in the Spring configuration file.

Spring:

```
<bean class="SampleBean">
    <property name="name"><value></value></property>
</bean>
```

Results in the name property being set to "", equivalent to the java code: sampleBean.setName(""). 
The special `<null>` element may be used to indicate a null value, so that:

Spring:

```
<bean class="ExampleBean">
    <property name="email"><null/></property>
</bean>
```

The above configuration is equivalent to the java code:

Java:

```
exampleBean.setEmail(null).
```

See this link: http://www.java-forums.org/java-tip/3218-how-set-null-value-springs-configuration-file.html

Comment: You just copied and pasted this from http://www.java-forums.org/java-tip/3218-how-set-null-value-springs-configuration-file.html Please cite your sources.