# Prevent Spring from instantiating certain beans during unit tests

Tags: spring, junit, jndi

The production applicationContext.xml defines several beans, seen below (mostly JMS resources) that are only relevant while deployed in production. The unit tests have mock implementations that completely bypass any JMS.

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="jmsConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:/JmsXA" resource-ref="false" proxy-interface="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory"/>
<jee:jndi-lookup id="myQueue" jndi-name="java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/myQueue"/>
<bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="myMessageHandler" class="com.example.MyMessageHandler" />
<bean id="jndiDestinationResolver" class="org.springframework.jms.support.destination.JndiDestinationResolver"/>
```

With the above in the main applicationContext.xml, I get the following exception during the tests since there is no JNDI container available.

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:662)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:344)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:154)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:178)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:95)
    at org.springframework.jndi.support.SimpleJndiBeanFactory.getBean(SimpleJndiBeanFactory.java:113)
```

Is it possible to tell Spring not to attempt to load those beans (whose ids I know) in the test applicationContext.xml? Or have a "null bean" since I know they will never be used? This would be less work than mocking them like in [How to test a mocked JNDI datasource with Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940895/how-to-test-a-mocked-jndi-datasource-with-spring)  .

Comment: use two applications config files; one for production and one for unit tests.

Comment: I do; the test one overrides some of the beans in production, that's the one in which I hoped to tell Spring to ignore or set those beans to null (I just tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163182/intentionally-setting-a-spring-bean-to-null, but as a comment there said, it doesn't work with autowired dependencies).

Comment: remove and/or replace with mocks the stuff you dont want in the unit test environment.  I'm old school about this; I have two seperate (in all ways) versions of my application configs for production and unit test.

Comment: Possible, yet for this project it'd be painful, there are > 200 beans,  declared via annotations. Having a <bean> for each is somewhat inconvenient. I'll have a look at Spring profiles (http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/)

Comment: I disagree with DwB about test vs production context files in general. See answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I suggest in general is the following. Break up your context files into multiple files. Generally isolate the beans that should not be used during testing in a separate context file. Have a single context file that imports all the bean definition files.

For your test, only load the files with the beans that you need for the test. If you have a bean A that you need for the test and depends on bean B, use [Springockito's @ReplaceWithMock](https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/wiki/springockito-annotations) to mock B and inject it into the context.

In your case I would suggest moving your jndi-lookup beans into a separate context and mocking / replacing `jmsConnectionFactory` or `jmsTemplate` (I would lean towards replacing `jmsTemplate`).